# Detectar si se ha hecho click dentro de un Div

Tags: javascript, div, click

Busco la manera de detectar si se ha hecho **click** dentro de un `div` sin importar el contenido que se encuentre dentro del **div** en cuestión.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#armaz  *').on('click', function()
{ alert($(this).prop('id')); });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="armaz" ><iframe>Contenido</iframe></div>
```

Como pueden ver no consigo hacerlo funcionar. Explico que el contenido dentro del `div` es variado pueden ser todo tipo de objeto, lo que necesito es que detecte si han hecho click al contenido del `div` sin importar cual sea el su contenido ejemplo un iframe.

Comment: La conjuncion verbal "haber hecho" es ambas con h. Te lo edito para que no duela.

Comment: Estás seleccionando un elemento cualquiera dentro del `div` llamado armaz ('#armaz  *' )en lugar de seleccionar directamente el div: `$('#armaz')`

Comment: $('#armaz').click(function() { alert($(this).prop('id'));})

Comment: Esa última edición cambia la cosa, un iframe es un caso excepcional porque el contenido el externo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es necesario emplear el selector universal para este fin. bastaría solo con escuchar el evento `click` para las etiquetas `div` sea cual sea el id o el contenido.

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click','div', function(){ 
  alert($(this).prop('id'));
 });
});
```

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background :#ccc;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="armaz" >Contenido</div>
<div id="armaz1" >Contenido</div>
<div id="armaz2" >Contenido</div>
<div id="armaz3" >Contenido</div>
```

> Como recomendación debería leer la [documentación de on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  para
>   saber como emplear este método y que parámetros debe enviar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta aun tengo la duda de detectar si an echo click dentro del contenido del iframe.

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions no es posible detectar el evento `click` de un contenido externo mediante `iframe`.  puede usar [librerias](https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery) o `hacks`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente añade el evento click al div

```
$( "#armaz" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: `<div id="admask">
  <iframe >cuatro metros</iframe>
</div><script> $('#armaz').click(function() { 
alert($(this).prop('id'));})</script> `  No funciona si es en Iframe

Comment: Eso no esta en la pregunta, si hacemos mal la pregunta no esperes que la respuesta se adecue a aquello que no has indicado. Un iframe no ve directamente el contenido padre.

Comment: No solo un iframe también imágenes o otro contenido como explico en la pregunta

Comment: Si es contenido propio de la pagina te va a funcionar, pero si esta en un iframe no porque se considera algo "externo"