# ¿Cómo hacer un div clickeable?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy en el proceso de hacer un "quiz de amigos". Estoy intentando que cada vez que seleccione un cuadro con la imagen como respuesta se marque en verde. **El problema es que no sé como hacer que un `div` tenga la función de botón.** Osea que al clickear sobre el se ejecute una función o algo.

Este es mi intento de código:

```
<div id="click1" class="set1of1of1" onclick="validation">
    <div class="img-1-1-1">
        <img class="jpg1" src="Images/pera.jpg" style="height: 200px; width: 220px;">
    </div>

    <div class="txt1-1-1">
        Texto
    </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿ Te sirve ? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86932/detectar-si-se-ha-hecho-click-dentro-de-un-div

Comment: @EduBw lastimosamente no, para el método que describe esa pregunta es necesario el uso de Jquery. ://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes añadir el evento `click` sobre el elemento que deseas mediante un selector. Este selector puede ser cualquiera de [estos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors),  básicamente son los selectores de CSS.

```js
function miFunc(e) { 
   alert(e.target.textContent);
}

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', miFunc);
```

```html
<div>hello world!</div>
```

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)